# python-mysql cursor.execute failing with access denied error

Tags: python, mysql

I have two machines: local_machine, server_machine. I have mysql server on server_machine and sftp server on local_machine. I am trying to send `sritest.csv` file (UTF-8) from local_machine to server_machine using python. These are the contents of `sritest.csv`:
`1,2,3`

I have the sql query saved in `sritest.sql` and these are the contents of the file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '{}'
INTO TABLE TESTBED_STAGING.test
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
;
```

This is the python script I have now:

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import string

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect (host="1.2.3.4",port=3306,user="app_1",\
                      passwd="passwd",db="TESTBED_STAGING")

cursor=db.cursor()
#Query under testing
sql = open('sritest.sql','r').read()
print sql
l = os.listdir(".")
for file_name in l:
    if file_name.endswith('sritest.csv'):
        print 'the csv file we are reading is: '+file_name
        #try:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        print 'filename is '+sql.format(file_name)
        cursor.execute(sql.format(file_name))
        db.commit()
        '''
        except Exception:
            # Rollback in case there is any error
            db.rollback()
            print 'ERROR - So, rollback :( :( '
        '''
# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

In the above script, I commented `try`,`except` so I can see the error where it breaks. Currently the code is breaking at `cursor.execute(sql.format(file_name))` line with this error:

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'app_1'@'%' (using password: YES)")
```

I have been playing around but not able to fix it. Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, creating cursor at every loop is not a good idea. You've already created a cursor earlier, so you can remove the cursor declaration in the `for` loop.

Second, I think your error is due to lack of access on MySQL server at 1.2.3.4 remotely using user `app_1`. Try this on the server's MySQL console,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TESTBED_STAGING.* TO 'app_1'@'%';
```

Lastly, try and avoid using `print "line"` notation and start switching to the `print("line")` notation for compatibility with Python 3.x

Comment: `app_1` user already has all the privileges on the MySQL server (I mean I ran the above command already).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer and decided to leave this question open for those who might face the similar problem:

1. In the MySQL server (server_machine), make sure you do this after you start mysql:
   `mysql>grant all privileges on *.* to 'app_1'@'%' identified by 'passwd';`
2. change `LOAD DATA INFILE '{}'` in `sritest.sql` to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{}'`
3. In the python code, edit the `MySQLdb.connect` statement as:
   `db = MySQLdb.connect (host="1.2.3.4",port=3306,user="app_1",\
                     passwd="passwd",db="TESTBED_STAGING", local_infile=1)`

All errors are eliminated and data is transferred.